# How do I incorporate JSON schema into my OpenAPI file?

Tags: swagger, openapi, jsonschema

Say I have an OpenAPI `swagger.yml` file that looks like:

```
openapi: '3.0.2'
info:
  title: Simplest ever
  version: '1.0'
servers:
  - url: https://api.server.test/v1
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  message:
                    type: string
```

I prefer to keep the source of truth schema in my schemas/ directory, for example `schemas/get.json` looks like:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "message": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

The intent is for the schemas/*.json to used in my backend code base for validation for incoming and outgoing messages. Goal is to have strong API contracts.

What I don't understand is how to build the `swagger.yml` file using these JSON schema, instead of duplicating the work in YAML which is really tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 15):

In OpenAPI 3.1, you can reference your JSON Schemas directly:

```yaml
          # openapi: 3.1.0

          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: 'schemas/get.json'
```

Earlier OpenAPI versions expect that the JSON Schemas be converted to the [OpenAPI Schema Object](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#schema-object) format (which can be represented as both YAML and JSON). The necessary changes include, for example:

- removing [unsupported keywords](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/): `$schema`, `patternProperties`, and others;
- replacing `type: [<foo>, 'null']` with `type: <foo>` + `nullable: true`;
- replacing other type arrays `type: [type1, type2, ...]` with `oneOf`/`anyOf` (OAS3) or removing them (OAS2).

[`json-schema-to-openapi-schema`](https://github.com/wework/json-schema-to-openapi-schema) can automate the conversion.

You can try to `$ref` vanilla JSON Schemas directly from OAS 2.0 and 3.0 definitions, but some tools will error out on unexpected keywords and constructs.